# Change entity type with Eclipselink / JPA?

Tags: jpa, inheritance, eclipselink

I'm aware of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098791/jpa-inheritance-change-the-entity-type) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744520/how-to-change-entity-type-in-jpa), but they were asked and answered in the scope of Hibernate. I've got the same problem, but I'm using Eclipselink and wondering if there are better or alternative solutions to what was proposed for Hibernate.

To recap the question shortly:

I have two classes which inherit from each other:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="dtype")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="parent")
public class Parent {
  @Id
  private long id;
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="child")
public class Child extends Parent{
   private String childProperty;
}
```

Now I'd like to change a Child into a Parent or vice versa, e.g.

```
Parent p = new Parent();
em.persist(p);

Child c = (Child) p;
em.merge(c);
```

I would expect that the database row for p now is of `dtype = child`.

The other way would be like this:

```
Child c = new Child();
em.persist(c);

Parent c = (Parent) c;
em.merge(c);
```

In this case, I would expect `c` to be saved with `dtype = parent` and losing the value of `childProperty`.

What described above does not work however, but I wrote it down to show what I mean.

Is there a way to do this with Eclipselink?

Comment: Please describe in terms of OOP, or give sample code, how to understand "change type" ?

Comment: I extended the description

Comment: It seems be unnaturally designed, after first wong step, next is wrong too. I'm not fluent in english to describe how to (in my understanding) resolve problem

Comment: 1st why?  Just casting the parent as a child does not change anything within the object itself.  Java objects do not morph - you create an instance of one and it remains that way.  If you need a child to become a parent, you create a new Parent instance - JPA works the same way.  If you want to have a flag within the object that tells you it is a parent or child, make a basic field for it that allows you to change it as needed.  But I would create the most generic root object that handles this 'inheritance' for you rather than rely on java inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to 'change' an object from one type to another, there is no simple solution with java or JPA inheritance.  You must clone your instance, remove the old one, then persist the new one to be JPA/Java compliant:

```
Child c = em.find(pk, Child.class);
Parent p = new Parent();
p.setId(c.getId());
p.setOtherFields(c.getOtherFields());

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.remove(c);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.clear();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(p);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Using the same transaction for it all 'might' work using flush instead of the commit/begin, but it isn't guaranteed as the managing the secondary cache gets tricky.  Also note that all relationships to the child need to be updated to point to the 'new' parent instance or the cache will be corrupted.

I'm not really sure the point though, since a Child IS a parent instance in this case already.  Nothing is gained by this approach other than an arbitrary flag in the database.  If you want it changeable on the fly, using Java subclasses might not be the right approach for your application.

Instead, I'd recommend using a generic Person that has field you can set to hold child/parent status.  But since a child can be a parent at the same time..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One problem I'm facing with this solution is that `em.remove(c);` also removes OneToMany-related-objects through cascade-persist. Do you know any way around this (besides removing cascade-persist), as I'd need the OneToMany-Objects on the new Parent-Object.

Comment: Null them out. You need to clean up any reference before deleting anyway, and then add those same references to your new instance.  This unfortunately includes fixing the bidirectional references, and won't be the most efficient approach due to the extra statements required.  If you aren't using a shared cache, you might be able to skip fixing remote references to point to the new instance, but limits the app in the future.